# What is the correct way to initialize HRESULT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2005 and I'm getting many warnings that read

```
potentially uninitialized local variable 'hr' used
```

Where hr is defined as

```
HRESULT hr;
```

What's the correct way to initialize HRESULT?

Comment: Don't ignore this warning, your code is bad.  The code that's not in your snippet.

Answer (score 6):

Pick an error `HRESULT` value and use that, so `HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED` or `HRESULT hr = E_FAIL` would be good choices I expect.

Comment: I guess I'm more optimistic :-) but I like this approach. +1

Comment: This tends to be more robust than S_OK. The reason is that there are more failure modes than success modes for most functions, and therefore more failure return paths. Yet the function is written to succeed, and most care is given to that return path. Thus it's very uncommon to forget the `hr = S_OK;` statement on the succesful return path, but missing `hr = E_FAIL` on a failure case happens all too often.

Comment: I always find it safer to assume failure... And the text for `E_UNEXPECTED` is just SO good ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
HRESULT hr = NOERROR;
```

You could also use

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
```

Both set it to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on chat you want:

- Fail by default ? Use `E_FAIL`
- Success by default ? use `S_OK`
- `hr` value is irrelevant if the subsequent code fails to initialize it ? Use `E_UNEXPECTED`

Answer (score 1):

Do not suppress the warnings by initializing the variables. The warnings are telling you that the code is Bad. Fix the code.

Some useful techniques:

- Declare variables as close to first use as practically possible.
- Translate error codes and `HRESULT`s to C++ exceptions.
- Wrap API functions that you use repeatedly and that have particularly ungood design.

Translating from `HRESULT` to exception can be done very concisely and almost readably by using the ["`>>` throwing pattern"](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/cppx-b-true-or-b-thrown-using-the-throwing-pattern/), like (although this example doesn't involve `HRESULT`s it shows that that pattern generalizes to handle most C style schemes) ...

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& stream, wchar_t const s[] )
{
    Size const  nBytes      = wcstombs( 0, s, 0 );
    (nBytes >= 0)
        || throwX( "wcstombs failed to deduce buffer size" );

    Size const              bufSize     = nBytes + 1;
    std::vector< char >     buf( bufSize );

    // The count of bytes written does not include terminating nullbyte.
    wcstombs( &buf[0], s, bufSize )
        >> Accept< IsNonNegative >()
        || throwX( "wcstombs failed to convert string" );

    return (stream << &buf[0]);
}
```

The support definitions needed for this are not complex at all, e.g. like

```
inline bool throwX( std::string const& s )
{
    throw Failure( s );
}

template< class Predicate >
struct Accept: Predicate
{};

template< class Type, class Predicate >
inline bool operator>>( Type const& v, Accept< Predicate > const& isOK )
{
    return isOK( v );
}

struct IsNonNegative
{
    template< class Type >
    bool operator()( Type const& v ) const { return (v >= 0); }
};
```

Comment: Hmm, yet another `>>` overload? Is that really what the world needs? ;)

Comment: @jalf: I'm not aware of any other `>>` overloads (except in iostreams).

Comment: @Alf: yeah, that's the one I'm referring to. That one is already fairly controversial. :)

Comment: And if we happen to be working in C where none of this is possible?

Comment: @Len: I don't know a good answer to your question about C (at least when assuming you mean standard C), sorry. Happily the OP's question was about C++. C lacks automated cleanup, and I'd probably be as a fish on land if I tried to code C with my current habits! :-)

Comment: My point was that initialising the variable is something that everyone can do. I don't disagree with your point that we should be declaring the variable at point of first use, or that exceptions are likely a better route...